# Syntax Highlighter for a Domain Specific Language

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, dsl, gedit

I have a DSL for which I intend to create a syntax highlighter for editors like vim, gedit and netbeans.

Has anyone tried this before?

Many thanks for any directions.

Ketan

Comment: If you had designed the DSL as an external DSL usign Eclipse TMF Xtext, you would have customizable syntax highlightning out of the box for the generated editor.

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to use eDSLs which falls under the same syntax conventions as their host languages. Lisp is especially suitable for this approach.

Comment: An embedded DSL, which is hosted within another language. A famous LOOP macro in Common Lisp is a good example of such a DSL.